# Overload resolution with multiple functions and multiple conversion operators

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, conversion-operator

Consider simple code :

```
#include<iostream>

struct A {
    operator double(){
        std::cout<<"Conversion function double chosen."<<std::endl;
        return 1.1;
    }
    operator char(){
        std::cout<<"Conversion function char chosen."<<std::endl;
        return 'a';
    }
} a;

void foo(int){}
void foo (char){}
int main() {
    foo(a);
}
```

Above code works fine, and as expected **gcc, clang and VC++** chooses `foo(char)`.

Now lets modify the code little bit :

```
#include<iostream>

struct A {
    operator double(){
        std::cout<<"Conversion function double chosen."<<std::endl;
        return 1.1;
    }
    operator char(){
        std::cout<<"Conversion function char chosen."<<std::endl;
        return 'a';
    }
} a;

void foo(int){}
void foo (double){} //parameter changed from char to double
int main() {
    foo(a);
}
```

Now this should have choose `foo(double)`, but seems only **VC++** is happy with the code while **clang and gcc** are unhappy with the above code.

```
main.cpp:11:10: error: call of overloaded 'foo(A&)' is ambiguous
 foo(a);
     ^
main.cpp:8:6: note: candidate: void foo(int)
 void foo(int){}
      ^
main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: void foo(double)
 void foo (double){} //parameter changed from char to double
      ^
```

Can anyone explain why above code fails? or is it bug?.

**One more question**: Do gcc and clang share code of overload resolution?

Comment: 1: Define "unhappy". 2: What happens if you remove `foo(int)`?

Comment: @Amit unhappy means code is rejected, and as for removal of function `foo(int)`, it's not part of question, you can try it yourself please.

Comment: @AngelusMortis: which function does VC++ choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A -> char` is `A -> char`.

`A -> int`  is `A -> char -> int` (because `char` to `int` is a promotion and so beats the `double` to `int` conversion).

`A -> double` is `A -> double`.

Two user-defined conversion sequences are only comparable if they involve the same user-defined conversion function. Thus, `A -> char` is a better conversion sequence than `A -> int`, so your first case is unambiguous. Neither `A -> int` nor `A -> double` is better than the other, so the second case is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: The difference is that in the first case, as opposed to the second, the user-defined conversion sequences (`A -> char`, `A -> int`) call the same conversion function (`operator char`). That enables us to break the tie via [over.ics.rank]/(3.3).

---

The best conversion operators for particular functions are selected by  [[over.match.best]/(1.4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1) (comparing the conversion sequences of their return types).

Hence the better conversion function for `foo(int)` is `operator char` followed by a promotion to `int`, as opposed to `operator double` followed by a floating point conversion.

Now consider both variants of the second overload:

1. The best ICS to `foo(char)` is **also via `operator char`** (identity better than floating point conversion). Thus [[over.ics.rank]/(3.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3) is applicable:

   > User-defined conversion sequence `U1` is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence `U2` **if they contain the same user-defined conversion function** […] and in either case the second standard conversion sequence of `U1` is better than the second standard conversion sequence of `U2`.

   Hence the overall conversion to `F2` is deemed better, and it is selected.
2. The best ICS to `foo(double)` is **via `operator double`**. We end up with two conversion sequences employing distinct conversion functions; nothing really applies, and we just get an ambiguity.