# Overloaded function and multiple conversion operators ambiguity in C++, compilers disagree

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, overload-resolution, conversion-operator

In the following program struct `S` provides two conversion operators: in `double` and in `long long int`. Then an object of type `S` is passed to a function `f`, overloaded for `float` and `double`:

```
struct S {
    operator double() { return 3; }
    operator long long int() { return 4; }
};

void f( double ) {}
void f( float ) {}

int main() {
    S s;
    f( s );
}
```

MSVC compiler accepts the program fine, selecting `f( double )` overload. However both GCC and Clang see an ambiguity in the calling of `f`, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5csd5dfYz

It seems that MSVC is right here, because the conversion:
`operator long long int()` -> `f( float )` is not a promotion. Is it wrong?

There is a similar question [Overload resolution with multiple functions and multiple conversion operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070303/overload-resolution-with-multiple-functions-and-multiple-conversion-operators), but there is a promotion case in it and all compilers agree now, unlike the case in this question.

Comment: Even changing the `long long int` conversion operator to `bool` doesn't help, which seems very unfortunate, intuitively no one would think bool->float is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC and Clang are correct. The implicit conversion sequences (user-defined conversion sequences) are indistinguishable.

[[over.ics.rank]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.ics.rank#3):

(emphasis mine)

> Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are
> indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the following
> rules applies:
>
> ...
>
> (3.3) User-defined conversion sequence U1 is a better conversion sequence
> than another user-defined conversion sequence U2 **if they contain the
> same user-defined conversion function** or constructor or they
> initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization and in either
> case the second standard conversion sequence of U1 is better than the
> second standard conversion sequence of U2.

The user-defined conversion sequences involves two different user-defined conversion functions (`operator double()` and `operator long long int()`), so compilers can't select one; the 2nd standard conversion sequence won't be considered.